# copy and modify elements to use them on another part of an html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider with 4 images, and I want to use the slider markup, to generate thumbnails on another part of my document. For this case I used data attributes with the needed information for the thumbnails.

Here is the Code from the Slider Part:

```
        <div id="sliderWrapper">
            <div id="slider">
                <div class="image" data-slide="1" data-thumb="thumb1.jpg" style="background-image: url('slide1.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="image" data-slide="2" data-thumb="thumb2.jpg" style="background-image: url('slide2.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="image" data-slide="3" data-thumb="thumb3.jpg" style="background-image: url('slide3.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="image" data-slide="4" data-thumb="thumb4.jpg" style="background-image: url('slide4.jpg');"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This Markup should be used, to generate the following:

```
        <div id="sliderThumbs">
            <a class="item" data-slide="1" style="background-image: url('thumb1.jpg');"></a>
            <a class="item" data-slide="2" style="background-image: url('thumb2.jpg');"></a>
            <a class="item" data-slide="3" style="background-image: url('thumb3.jpg');"></a>
            <a class="item" data-slide="4" style="background-image: url('thumb4.jpg');"></a>
        </div>
```

The question is, how I could "copy" and "modify" the markup.

My first try was to get the children of the slider div using jquery:

```
var images = $('#slider').children('div').map(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
}).get();
```

But this isn't working so good. I hope someone can help me to achieve this. How can I get all four divs and use the data attributes to generate the needed markup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find/attribute setting to create a new element based upon the source element and use $.append() to add it onto the target element...

[Here's a fiddle with a working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/traceline/zzLd168o/2/)

```
$("div.image").click(function(e){

    var clicked = $(e.target);
    var imageURL= "url('" + clicked.attr("data-thumb") + "')";
    var toAppend = $("<a>")
                        .attr("data-slide", clicked.attr("data-slide"))
                        .css("background-image", imageURL)
                        .addClass("item")
                        .text("added "+ clicked.text());

    $("#sliderThumbs").append(toAppend);
});
```

---

Edited the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/traceline/zzLd168o/4/) to do on document load for each div.

```
    $("div.image").each(function(index, d){

    var div = $(d);
    var imageURL= "url('" + div.attr("data-thumb") + "')";
    var toAppend = $("<a>")
                        .attr("data-slide", div.attr("data-slide"))
                        .css("background-image", imageURL)
                        .addClass("item")
                        .text("added "+ div.text());

    $("#sliderThumbs").append(toAppend);
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your fiddle, but I don't need it on click. If the page is loaded, the markup should be generated and added in a special div on my page.

Comment: Ah - that's easy - will alter fiddle to show - was just trying to convey the mechanism of how each bit is done... .hold on

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
var count = 1;
var img = $('#slider > .image').each(function(){           
if($(this).attr('data-thumb')){             
    var vimg = $(this).attr('data-thumb');
    var data = "<a class='item' data-slide='"+count+"' style='background-image: url("+vimg +")';></a>"
    console.log(data);   
   count++;         
             };
   });
});
```